# Why does Glue Databrew job write empty CSV files when dumping the output into S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

It appears to be dividing the output of my job into several very small CSV files when it saves them in S3, but some of them are 0 B.

Just to clarify: this is the output produced by just 1 job execution. I've configured the job to write the result in S3 as CSV. Glue Databrew dumps the output in several CSVs for some reason, and thats ok, **but why some of them are empty?**

[image]

Comment: did you get any solution for above issue?

Comment: I found that DataBrew does not workproperly if dataset has partitions and then it creats empty files in output and sometimes add empty rows in the outputs.

Answer (score 3):

When outputting, Glue will create a file for each thread that was running (really these are Hadoop threads under Spark). If a thread ran, but ended up having nothing to output it will output an empty file.
If you wanted to consolidate the threads back into a single thread (and therefore single file) before outputting you could do something like the code below (assuming Python). This assumes that frame variable below is a Glue DynamicFrame.
Note that this will have some performance impact.

```
frame = frame.repartition(1)# ensure output is a single file
```

Do this just before you do your write of your frame out to S3.

Comment: You can also put a request to AWS Support to get output consolidated into one file. This will have performance as well as cost implications (slower and more expensive).